# Querying an ontologie without knowing classes

Tags: jena, ontology

I want to query MESH Ontology, it contains more than 281776 class.
I want to have for example all the classes related to the word "dentistry" 
How should I write the query with java Jena?
This is the form of the data in the ontology

```
<!-- http://bioonto.de/mesh.owl#D003813 -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://bioonto.de/mesh.owl#D003813">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Dentistry</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://bioonto.de/mesh.owl#E06"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://bioonto.de/mesh.owl#H02.163"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://bioonto.de/mesh.owl#D003814 -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://bioonto.de/mesh.owl#D003814">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Dentistry, Operative</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://bioonto.de/mesh.owl#E06.323"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://bioonto.de/mesh.owl#H02.163.180"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://bioonto.de/mesh.owl#D003815 -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://bioonto.de/mesh.owl#D003815">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Dentists</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://bioonto.de/mesh.owl#M01.526.485.330"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://bioonto.de/mesh.owl#N02.360.330"/>
</owl:Class>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
    import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
    import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
    import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
    import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
    import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    public class Test { 

        // absolute path to your owl file
        static final String inputFileName = "path and file name";


        public static void main (String [] args) {  

                // creating ontology model without reasoner specification
                OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();    
                // opening input owl file
                InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName);     
                // reading input owl file
                model.read(in, "");
                // getting all classes
                ExtendedIterator classes = model.listClasses();
                //iterating classes
                while (classes.hasNext()) {
                    OntClass cls = (OntClass) classes.next();
                    // getting local class name - without prefix
                    String className = cls.getLocalName();
                    // case sensitive string containment check
                    if (className.contains("dentistry"));                   
                        System.out.print(className + "\n");             

                }
        }

    }
```